# iOS - How to set a refresh rate on ads in LeadBolt sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ads, leadbolt

When my app loads, it shows the same banner ad for the entire session. Is there a method for cycling in new ads, like refreshing the current banner to show the next ad? This is killing my impressions and conversions. As one ad shown the entire session isn't really going to appeal too much to the user. I know that from reading over the documentation that loadAd() has something to do with it but I cant seem to figure out how to actually implement that time interval. Here is my code for whats going on now with leadbolt in the view Im showing the banner in. This is all part of - (void)viewDidLoad, I just left out all the other stuff not relevant to the ads.

```
    overlay = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    titleBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    footerBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    clickTitleBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    clickFooterBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    mask = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [self.view insertSubview:mask atIndex:2];
    [self.view insertSubview:clickTitleBar atIndex:3];
    [self.view insertSubview:clickFooterBar atIndex:4];
    [self.view insertSubview:titleBar atIndex:5];
    [self.view insertSubview:footerBar atIndex:6];
    [self.view insertSubview:overlay atIndex:7];
    overlay.delegate = overlayController;

    //initialize the overlayController 
    overlayController  = [[LeadboltOverlay alloc] init];

    [overlayController setSectionid:@"MY AD #"];
    [overlayController setAdWebView:self.overlay];
    [overlayController setCloseBar:self.titleBar];
    [overlayController setFooterBar:self.footerBar];
    [overlayController setClickCloseBar:self.clickTitleBar];
    [overlayController setClickFooterBar:self.clickFooterBar];
    [overlayController setLocationControl:@"0"];
    [overlayController setMask:self.mask];

    ///////This part here?///////
    [overlayController loadAd];
    /////////////////////////////

    overlay.delegate = overlayController;

    self.stsTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkCompleted) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.stsTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 2):

To refresh ads (perhaps every minute or every time there is an event in the UI) you could just set up a HTML banner in a UIWebView and call myWebview reload] each time you want a new ad to be shown.

It's not recommended to [overlayController loadAd] repeatedly as it can cause memory management issues.